# shared data between task - mpi

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am working on MPI with c++ for parallel program on visual studio 2012 and HPC pack from microsoft

when i run my program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char * argv[]){     
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int i = 0;
    i++;

    cout << "i = " << i << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

when i run in cmd :

```
mpiexec App.exe
```

the out put is :

```
1
1
1
1
```

how to make the ' i ' variable is shared between all task and each of task increase its value so the output became :

```
1
2
3
4
```

how to do that ?

thanks for advance

Comment: Check `MPI_Get_accumulate()`

Comment: MPI is about message passing, not about shared memory (even if there are some functionalities in modern MPI). You should start with introduction level material on MPI.

Comment: thanks for information